# How to read the benchmark result?

Tags: pallet, weight, benchmarking

A benchmark test for function with a param like this:

```rs
runner_execute {

    let x in 1..10000000;

    ...

    let gas_limit_call = x as u64;

}: {
    ...

    let call_runner_results = T::Runner::call(
        ...
        gas_limit_call,
        ...
    );
}
```

The benchmark result:

```rs
impl WeightInfo for () {
    // Storage: System Account (r:1 w:0)
    // Storage: Ethereum RemainingRingBalance (r:1 w:0)
    // Storage: EVM AccountCodes (r:1 w:0)
    // Storage: EVM AccountStorages (r:1 w:0)
    fn runner_execute(x: u32, ) -> Weight {
        (5_773_816_000 as Weight)
            // Standard Error: 0
            .saturating_add((38_000 as Weight).saturating_mul(x as Weight))
            .saturating_add(RocksDbWeight::get().reads(4 as Weight))
            .saturating_add(RocksDbWeight::get().writes(1 as Weight))
    }
}
```

In terms of db read and write weight, it's very clear, but how do you understand `(5_773_816_000 as Weight)`? Could I get a more detailed weight consumption report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic number there is not very helpful, I agree. We will change that [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11215).

One unit of *weight* is equivalent to `10^-12` seconds.
Your extrinsic therefore always takes at least 5.774 milliseconds to execute.
The 38_000 means that the weight of your extrinsic increases linear for each `gas_limit_call` by 38 ns.

Currently the execution time, storage Reads/Writes and PoV size are the only thing that are measured.
The weights will also take the PoV size into account [soon](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10918).

A more detailed report is printed by the node, you should see something like (older versions try `--raw`):

```
Pallet: "pallet_lottery", Extrinsic: "set_calls", Lowest values: [], Highest values: [], Steps: 50, Repeat: 20                                                                                                                                 
Raw Storage Info    
========                                                   
Storage: Lottery CallIndices (r:0 w:1)
                                           
Median Slopes Analysis                     
========                         
-- Extrinsic Time --             
                                           
Model:                                     
Time ~=    18.44                 
    + n    0.463                 
              µs                 
                                           
Reads = 0 + (0 * n)              
Writes = 1 + (0 * n)             
                                                     
Min Squares Analysis             
========                         
-- Extrinsic Time --             
                                                     
Data points distribution:        
    n   mean µs  sigma µs       %
    0     17.85     0.127    0.7%          
    1     19.29     0.122    0.6%
    2     19.55     0.113    0.5%                    
    3     19.83     0.246    1.2%
    4     20.36     0.232    1.1%          
    5     20.91     0.138    0.6%                    
    6     21.04     0.133    0.6%                    
    7      21.7     0.133    0.6%                    
    8      22.1     0.155    0.7%                    
    9     22.76     0.232    1.0%                          
   10     22.92     0.196    0.8%                    
                                                     
Quality and confidence:                                    
param     error                                            
n         0.009                                            

Model:                                                     
Time ~=    18.42                                           
    + n    0.466                                           
              µs                                           

Reads = 0 + (0 * n)                                        
Writes = 1 + (0 * n)
```

On newer substrate versions its possible to pass in the `--json` or `--json-file <PATH>` flags
to access the raw results in a machine-readable manner.

One final tip: Your `10000000` is also a magic number , you could add a Config value instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found another point, the second line `((38_000 as Weight).saturating_mul(x as Weight))`, do you know how `38_000` is generated? Can I see this as `T::Runner::call(...)` varying weight consumption as `gas_limit_call` changes?

Comment: Yes. The benchmarking uses linear regression to find any linear dependency between the input parameters and the weight. The 38 ns is multiplied with your x aka `gas_limit_call`. parameter.  
The exact result and linear model should be printed to console as shown above.
PS: Updated my answer.